# Error ITMS-90203 in Xcode during Appstore Submission

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I got the following error during the Appstore submission:

[image: Error ITMS-90203]

I double checked that all targets and linked pods and subprojects have

[image: Target settings]

I even tried `lipo -info <my_binary>` and it said `arm64 armv7 armv7s`

So whats wrong with my submission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a framework that is not built for 64bit. Apple now requires all app submissions be 64-bit compatible.

Comment: how can i find out which framework this could be? I ran `lipo -info` against all linked frameworks and all of them showed `arm64` - but there are some pods that are compiled during the build-progress. Is there an indicator wether they are 64-bit or not?

Comment: You were totally right! I found out that i imported a framework the wrong way using an embedded binary.. This one does not got recompiled when i changed the architectures. After I removed i, recompiled it and  imported it again using "Link Binary with Libraries" it worked like a charm - Thank you!